# How to import text via AVCaptureSession similar to how Apple captures credit card info for Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, ocr, avcapturesession, scanning, applepay

Does anyone know how I could replicate the method Apple uses to capture credit card info when setting up Apple Pay? I'd like to use the camera to capture a string via AVCaptureSession rather than having the user take a photo then run that through OCR (which I'm currently doing). It would appear to be more seamless if I could capture the data without taking a picture first.

I guess this would also be similar to creating a bar code scanner, but would detect text instead of reading bar codes.

I've searched google and stackoverflow relentlessly but couldn't find anything relevant to what I'm looking for...

Swift is preferred but Obj-C would be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know it's been quite a while since I had posted this question, but I'm still interested in learning how to implement this. Any insight is appreciated!